# Can you compensate for incorrect thermals being reported to the kernel to prevent throttling?

Tags: linux, kernel, cpu, battery, bugs

I have faulty battery firmware or something, because my otherwise healthy battery now refuses to charge normally, and what is worse, 80% of the time, it has me bizarrely throttled down to 400mhz per core, and changing my cpu governors or scaling has not worked for me. That being said, if I disconnect the internal battery, ( This is a thinkpad x1 yoga 1st generation ) A battery is still reported, just that its value is 0% and says it is charging. The throttling still occurs so it might be my motherboard.

The only time my laptop works at the proper speed, is when its been off for a day, discharged, and I plug it in. It will then Charge maybe up to 50% - 85%, before something switches, and my laptop then enters into a discharging state, while plugged in, and my cpu throttles back down to 400mhz!
Sometimes randomly it will also go into the proper state for a few minutes.

The last time this happened, I recorded a diff of `/sys/devices/system/` And omitting memory and nodes, this was what I produced:

https://www.irccloud.com/pastebin/SXa75ldh/system

Interesting areas to note are

```bsh
Only in Incorrect State/system/cpu/cpu0: crash_notes
Only in Incorrect State/system/cpu/cpu0: crash_notes_size
diff --color -sdyr "Incorrect State/system/cpu/cpu0/thermal_throttle/core_throttle_count" "Correct State/system/cpu/cpu0/thermal_throttle/core_throttle_count"
2906                                  | 0
diff --color -sdyr "Incorrect State/system/cpu/cpu0/thermal_throttle/package_throttle_count" "Correct State/system/cpu/cpu0/thermal_throttle/package_throttle_count"
3483                                  | 0
...
Only in Correct State/system: system
```

The Crash notes appear to be a memory address.

```
➜  cpu0 sudo cat crash_notes
431231e00
➜  cpu0 sudo cat crash_notes_size
368
➜  cpu1 sudo cat crash_notes
4312b1e00
➜  cpu1 sudo cat crash_notes_size 
368
```

The thermal_throttle seems to be the issue here. I compared with a user with a normally functioning system, and his registered 0's as well. Further Research has demonstrated that I am likely suffering from this issue here:

https://superuser.com/questions/459354/the-meaning-of-thermal-throttle-counters-and-package-power-limit-notifications-i

My thinking is that if I can either change the values down to 0, or tell the kernel to ignore them, I might be able to stop its throttling. That also sounds like a bad idea, but I am willing to do it if there is no alternative, because this throttling is driving me crazy, and the laptop will not be good to me if it remains at that speed in perpetituity, as I wont be able to use it as a server or anything like that.

1. What are normal thermal numbers under a heavy load? Right now with my laptop perfectly cool, I am showing

```bsh
➜  thermal_throttle cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/thermal_throttle/package_throttle_count
3483
3483
3483
3483

➜  thermal_throttle cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/thermal_throttle/core_throttle_count                                                                        
2906
779
2906
779
```

2. Is there any way I can compensate for incorrect thermals being reported to the kernel? Perhaps by simply dividing the value so it is less exaggerated?
3. Can I permeanently change or alter the values?
4. Can I tell the kernel to ignore the values?

I am willing to write software to do this.

---

Doing some testing on my sensors and thermals, I can heat up my laptop censors by 5 or so degrees centigrade, however the values of `core_throttle_count` and `package_throttle_count` remain static. This would imply that some of my sensors are accurate, and can be relied upon if I need to build my own driver.

---

I might be incorrect about the thermals. Upon a reboot, the numbers are reporting 0's across the board, and I have no change in the throttling.

Answer (score 1):

There exists a battery firmware update for Thinkpads, but you need Windows to apply it.
Please check if your battery is supported.

[Lenovo Battery Firmware Update Utility for Windows 10, 8.1, 8, 7, Vista (32-bit, 64-bit), XP - ThinkPad](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds001322-lenovo-battery-firmware-update-utility-for-windows-10-81-8-7-vista-32-bit-64-bit-xp-thinkpad)

> Supported Batteries
>
> ---
>
> This is not an urgent update; the problem will manifest itself over a
> period of months. Eventually, the battery will erroneously indicate
> that it can no longer hold any charge, but this effect is slow and
> accumulating. Large enterprise customers can plan to do this update
> during their next planned system maintenance.
>
> The battery firmware update is applicable to the FRU part numbers
> shown below. The battery firmware update will change the FRU number
> electronically stored in the battery (which is reported by Power
> Manager). This is done as one way to confirm that the battery firmware
> update has been completed. Obviously, the printed label will still
> show the "old" FRU number.
>
> - FRU P/N : 42T4708 (ASM P/N : 42T4709)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4714 (ASM P/N : 42T4715)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4737 (ASM P/N : 42T4738)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4757 (ASM P/N : 42T4758)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4797 (ASM P/N : 42T4796)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4803 (ASM P/N : 42T4802)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4783 (ASM P/N : 42T4782)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4789 (ASM P/N : 42T4788)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4831 (ASM P/N : 42T4830)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4807 (ASM P/N : 42T4806)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4815 (ASM P/N : 42T4814)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4839 (ASM P/N : 42T4838)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4848 (ASM P/N : 42T4758)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4849 (ASM P/N : 42T4709)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4850 (ASM P/N : 42T4738)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4851 (ASM P/N : 42T4715)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4852 (ASM P/N : 42T4796)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4853 (ASM P/N : 42T4802)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4854 (ASM P/N : 42T4782)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4855 (ASM P/N : 42T4788)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4856 (ASM P/N : 42T4830)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4857 (ASM P/N : 42T4806)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4858 (ASM P/N : 42T4814)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4929 (ASM P/N : 42T4928)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4933 (ASM P/N : 42T4932)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4937 (ASM P/N : 42T4936)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4939 (ASM P/N : 42T4938)
> - FRU P/N : 45N1039 (ASM P/N : 45N1038)
> - FRU P/N : 45N1143 (ASM P/N : 45N1038)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4710 (ASM P/N : 42T4711)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4739 (ASM P/N : 42T4740)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4799 (ASM P/N : 42T4798)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4805 (ASM P/N : 42T4804)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4813 (ASM P/N : 42T4812)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4829 (ASM P/N : 42T4828)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4841 (ASM P/N : 42T4840)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4861 (ASM P/N : 42T4862)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4879 (ASM P/N : 42T4880)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4889 (ASM P/N : 42T4890)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4940 (ASM P/N : 42T4868)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4943 (ASM P/N : 42T4944)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4947 (ASM P/N : 42T4948)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4953 (ASM P/N : 42T4954)
> - FRU P/N : 42T4957 (ASM P/N : 42T4958)
> - FRU P/N : 45N1007 (ASM P/N : 45N1006)
> - FRU P/N : 45N1017 (ASM P/N : 45N1016)
> - FRU P/N : 45N1023 (ASM P/N : 45N1022)
> - FRU P/N : 45N1027 (ASM P/N : 45N1026)
> - FRU P/N : 45N1057 (ASM P/N : 45N1056)
> - FRU P/N : 45N1061 (ASM P/N : 45N1060)
> - FRU P/N : 45N1077 (ASM P/N : 45N1076)
> - FRU P/N : 45N1751 (ASM P/N : 45N1750)
> - FRU P/N : 45N1749 (ASM P/N : 45N1748)
> - FRU P/N : 01AV403 (ASM P/N : SB10J79000)
> - FRU P/N : 45N1103 (ASM P/N : 45N1102)
> - FRU P/N : 45N1067 (ASM P/N : 45N1066)
> - FRU P/N : 45N1071 (ASM P/N : 45N1070)
> - FRU P/N : 45N1087 (ASM P/N : 45N1086)
> - FRU P/N : 45N1757 (ASM P/N : 45N1756)
> - FRU P/N : 00HW001 (ASM P/N : SB10F46439)
> - FRU P/N : 45N1763 (ASM P/N : 45N1762)
> - FRU P/N : 45N1729 (ASM P/N : 45N1728)

Comment: you think I can do it through wine or a virtual machine?

Comment: No. You need Windows to check if your battery is affected.

Comment: *facepalm* I really dont want to do that, lol. Does windows have a live environment that I can do this with? OR maybe use ReactOS or something?

Comment: Check the FRU number on the sticker of your battery first.

Comment: I don't have a matching fru code, at least from what is being reported to my machine.